# Why can't I mention people on Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

The "*mention*" feature in Outlook 2016 where you can tag someone by typing `@ + person's name` has been rolled out over a year ago. I can use it on Outlook Android but still can't on Windows 10, despite me having what I think is the latest version: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 32 bit version 1706 build 8229.2073. It is syncing with Office 365.

Any idea why this feature isn't available to me on Desktop when it works in Android?

Answer (score 1):

I had to install `Office 365 Business` on top of my `Microsoft Office Professional Plus` in order to get that feature. With it also comes the new "Dictate" feature which will come handy.